# MPAndroidChart X axis labels not aligned with bar graph

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I'm creating Combined chart with line chart and group bar chart using [MPAndroidChart v3.0.2](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) but I found that the labels on the X-Axis are not aligned properly with the bar in group bar chart.

**Below is the screenshot for the same.**

[image: Screenshot]

**Code I am using for plotting the graph.**

```
xVals = new ArrayList();
            xVals.add("January");
            xVals.add("February");
            xVals.add("March");
            xVals.add("April");
            xVals.add("May");
            xVals.add("June");
            xVals.add("July");
            xVals.add("August");
            xVals.add("September");
            xVals.add("October");

            XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
            xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
            xAxis.setAxisMinimum(0);        xAxis.setAxisMaximum(mChart.getBarData().getGroupWidth(groupSpace, barSpace) * xVals.size());
            xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(false);
            xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
            xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
            xAxis.setTextSize(8);
            xAxis.setLabelCount(xVals.size());
            xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(xVals));
```

Comment: Can you please add screenshots and also code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have added block of code and screenshot

Comment: have you resolved this? I have a similar issue and it looks like it's related to the some kind of special handling for labels that are too long which breaks the positioning of nearby labels

Comment: yes...Add extra empty string in your X axis lable's array

Comment: can you explain the setMaximum()?